# In Excel for Mac 2011, how do I delete the name from a named cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

How do I delete the name from a named cell in Excel 2011 for Mac?

Answer (score 3):

Go to the *Insert* menu, then select *Name*, then *Define*. From there you will see all names used in your workbook, and can delete the one you no longer want.